# C# Winforms Custom WebBrowser Control Needed

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, controls

I have been searching the web lately for an existing control that acts like a web browser control, with some specific features that I need.

I haven't found one that has them, and so I wanted to leave a question here, hoping that someone can point out how I can do this, or even give me some tips on how to create one from scratch, which will ultimately be the solution.

I need a control that allows me to preview webpages, at the same time it allows me to edit it programatically. I don't need to write HTML or text directly into the editor, but need to be able to click a button, and insert specific HTML code to the document, and refresh the preview.

I also need to be able to capture click events on the control. For example, I want to click a specific place on the control and get the HTML element that is at the mouse position. Regarding events, I would also need to be able to capture drag-and-drop, and it seems that natively, the browser control doesn't also support this.

Even though I have tried out some different controls, none of them has these features, or allowed me to add them. So, I would really appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction, or maybe correct me if I am wrongly assuming it can't be done with any of the existing .NET controls.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such control. Moreover, writing one from scratch, that correctly rendered all modern HTML/CSS would be a major undertaking.

Even products like Microsoft Expression tends to have quirks in the way they display the HTML being edited.

I'm afraid you've got your work cut out for you.

Comment: Yes, actually I have considered that... It really cannot be easy to create a control that renders HTML with CSS. But there are a few controls out there, that seem to do some more stuff than just the browser control, and I doubt they have been done from scratch...

Comment: @BlunT: Well, there are open source rendering engines. So you could take something like that and modify it to allow editing. But I consider this more or less from scratch since you'll need to work with the original source code rather than just using a component.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

On the browser's client-side there are DOM accessors that will let you get HTML by mouse position.  Check out this page for a demonstration of this:

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/cssGetElementUnderMouse/index.html

Presumably you could write out javascript into your HTML that would have hooks in it to raise events in your parent UI code that could in turn interact with the browser.  Getting something that captures the HTML element name from the DOM, and passes it back to the UI, which uses it as a cursor into an HTMLDocument would be a good start.

From there you could probably extend that model to support ideas like drag/drop or on-the-fly refresh or what have you.

I don't know of anything that does this out of the box.  I did look around and come across this tool, which is billing itself as free and is providing source, but *I don't know what its license model is so **contact the author**.*

http://kompozer.net/features.php

Comment: I didn't get to answer this post, but kompozer does not seem to be a component to use with C#, but a standalone tool itself. I am back to searching because ModelText is getting me crazy. I am getting some "Unexpected" errors when trying to add some pieces of HTML, which don't give me lots of information on how to fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.modeltext.com/html/

Comment: ModelText is one of the controls that I have tried out, and tested using the examples they provided. I had already tried to capture events and I couldn't, but now I had another try and seem to at least get some parts to work. I'll dig a little deeper and let you know if it is able to do all I need. Do you have any experience with this control, or know where I can go to discuss if I have any doubts?

Comment: I never used it before. I was hoping it worked because it sounds like it could be very useful.

Comment: I am having some trouble setting the contents of the HTML programmatically, but I have managed to capture the events of the HTML controls when I click the page. It's a start!